# Blue prism code stage and adding event handler

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher, blueprism, rpa

I want to sense the activity in a specific folder in one blue prism process, if any file is pasted then trigger an event and run another blue prism process. I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2 link in C# to sense the folder activity. but I a not able to understand how to add it in code stage. as it will need to define event handler in same code stage. Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: I don't know C# enough to be able to understand the full code from the MSDN link, especially since control over the watcher should be at Process level in BluePrism (so you can tell BP to start/stop watching any time) and it looks like once this code provided as example starts running, it won't quit at all even if a change triggered an alert, so you'll need significant modification to the code there for it to be usable.

Answer (score 3):

You could add this to a `Code Stage` or a `Global Code` part of the object, but  I don't think this is good practice. Essentially, for this to work the code stage would need to be running constantly, essentially consuming one license full time. You might as well be running a loop checking files in a folder.

If you would like to start a BP process based on a file trigger without consuming a license you would need to write your own program/script that would run side by side next to Blue Prism.